# Generating wcf ServiceClients, reference problem

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I am trying to generate ServiceClient classes.

I have 2 Projects, API and WEB.
The API project contains both ClassLibrary and DataContracts/Interface class files. I have a website which has the SVC files. WEB references the API project.

When I to generate the the Service Client classes, they generate in the API project

**Here is the problem I am having**

My SvcUtil command line includes /Reference: [full location of API /bin/debug/API.dll ]. It is the same path as the build output from the API project.

When I run the SvcUtil command with that /Reference, the generation fails and I see the following cutdown summary of messages.

```
Attempting to download metadata from 
'http://id.unittest/Services/EchoService.svc?wsdl' 
using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Error: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: Cannot locate operation IsSubscribed in Contract IEchoService.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']
/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IEchoService']


Error: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent 
on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']
/wsdl:binding[@name='WSHttpBinding_IEchoService']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']
/wsdl:service[@name='EchoService']/wsdl:port[@name='WSHttpBinding_IEchoService']


Generating files...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata documents 
did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts/services were discovered to exist in /reference assemblies. 
Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure 
to use the /dataContractOnly option.
```

When I remove the /reference, the generation succeeds, but a duplicate set of entity classes that were used in the methods params are generated. When I try to build my API project, I get an error that there are duplicate classes names and that I should change them to partial. So, dont want and need those extra classes.

Hopefully I have provided enough information. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add the following switches to the svcutil command
`/serializer:DataContractSerializer /serializable`

Reference url: [MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/671fe835-759d-45b6-91a2-fd153d49e3c4?prof=required)

Comment: Dang I needed that ... what a pain this wsdl stuff is. Thanks, dude.